# Expected value of a transformed random variable

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-variable, expected-value, moment-generating-function

I would be interested in computing the expected value of the following random variable $Y$.

Let $X$ be either a $\mathrm{Bin}(p,N)$ or a $\mathrm{Hyp}(n,m,N)$ with $m$ number of successes (I would be interested in both proofs). Is there a way to compute the **expected value** of 
$$ Y = X \log X $$
I tried to go through the moment generating function but I haven't had any result yet.

Comment: Note: $X$ might be $0$, in which case $Y$ is undefined.

Comment: @ocram You are correct, but it is quite sensible to take $X\log X=0$, because that is the limiting value as $X$ goes to $0$ from above.

Comment: Simone, it is unlikely you will obtain anything simpler than the summation used to define the expectation. What do you need the expectation for?  Will numerical calculations do?  Asymptotic estimates?  Approximations?

Comment: @whuber: Yes, I thought the same about setting $0 \times \log 0 = 0$ because this is the limiting value. But I found it weird to take the limiting value for a discrete random variable...

Comment: It is a middle step to compute a mean entropy. An analytical solution would be interesting because much faster than the computation via summation.

Comment: Can I cross post it in math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: We could migrate if you want.  I can just about guarantee you won't get closed form formulas no matter where you post this question, but if you can indicate typical ranges of values of $p$ and $N$, it's likely you would get good approximate formulas on either site.  For instance, for $p N$ not too small, a saddlepoint approximation should do a pretty good job.

Comment: I thought it was an easier problem, I should go for an approximation then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, the expectation of $g(X)$ can often be approximated using a Taylor expansion around the mean; let $a=E(X)$

$$g(X) = g(a) + g'(a) (X-a) + \frac{1}{2!}g''(a) (X-a)^2 +\cdots$$

$$E[g(X)] = g(a) + \frac{1}{2!}g^{(2)}(a) \, m_2  + \frac{1}{3!}  g^{(3)}(a) \, m_3  + \cdots $$

where $g^{(n)}(a)$ is the $n-$th derivative of $g(X)$ evaluated at the mean, and $m_k$ is the $k-$th centered moment of $X$.

In our case, $g(X)=X \log(X)$ and  $g^{(n)}(a) = (-1)^n (n-2)! \; a^{-(n-1)}$ for $n>1$

So the expasion takes the form

$$ E[X \log X] \approx a \log a + \frac{1} {2 \times 1} \frac{m_2}{a} - \frac{1}{3 \times 2}\frac{m_3}{a^2} + \frac{1} {4 \times 3}\frac{m_4}{a^3} -\cdots$$

For the Binomial $(N,p)$, we get

$$ E[X \log X] \approx Np \log( Np) + \frac{1-p}{2} - \frac{(1-p)(1-2p)}{6 Np } + \cdots$$

And for the Hypergeometrix $(N, n, m)$

$$ E[X \log X] \approx a \log(a) + \frac{m}{2 (n+m)} - \cdots$$

where $a=E(X)=\frac{n N}{m+n}$ and i was too lazy to compute the next term.

It's seen that these are useful as  asymptotic expansions, for $N \to \infty$.

For finite $N$, this should be not be used if $a \lesssim 1$.

Here are a few values, for the Binomial aproximation up to the third moment:

```
           p=0.2               p=0.5         p=0.8
        exact   approx     exact  approx  exact  approx
N 5     0.4907  0.3200     2.5811 2.5407  5.6542 5.6502
N 10    1.8545  1.7463     8.3123 8.2972  16.740 16.738
N 20    5.9740  5.9252     23.283 23.276  44.463 44.463
```

As cardinal points out in the comments, using the mean-value form for the error of the truncated Taylor expansion, if we truncate at an odd-moment term, (as I did for the Binomial above) we see that the error must be positive, and hence we have obtained a lower bound of the exact value. This can also be proven using [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), because $g(x)=x \log x$ is a convex function.

Comment: This is a nice start, but please re-check your series coefficients: the signs seem to be incorrect. After all, $x \log(x)$ is convex and so must have a positive second derivative.

Comment: Entropy is closely tied to convexity. You might note in your answer that, because of the alternating signs of the derivative, stopping at an odd-order term will always yield a lower bound. Of course, in this case, it's not too sensible to use this method of approximation for more than order $N$. A graph depicting some approximations might be illustrative.

Comment: @cardinal: "because of the alternating signs of the derivative..." but we'd need to assert that the moments are positive and the terms decreasing in magnitude, don't we?

Comment: @leonbloy: No. The moments of even order *are* nonnegative and we need nothing regarding the terms being decreasing in magnitude, but rather just need to employ the mean-value theorem. (Notice I didn't say the sequence of approximations was necessarily monotone.) :-)

Comment: @cardinal: Ah, yes, you're right; I though you were alluding to the double bounds for a decreasing alternating series.

Comment: One other minor point: I think your equation for the $n$th order derivative is missing a factor of $(n-2)!$.

Comment: Sheez, I thought I remembered how to derive :-) Fortunately, that didn't affected my truncation (but I added another term to make it clear) Thanks

Comment: (+1) The exact vs. approximate comparisons for smallish $N$ don't really matter, because one might just as well do the full summation. A little more analysis--I'm not requesting that you do it!--would uncover the combinations of $(N,p)$ where the summation can safely be replaced by the approximation. We might go even further: the problematic cases will occur for small $p$ and large $N$, where we might redo the approximation for a Poisson distribution instead of a Binomial. In short, it looks your *procedure* has the potential to fully answer many variations of the original question.